# Apple Enterprise program for organisation’s employee app distribution for my client

Tags: ios, app-store

For *reference*, I will refer to:

My Organisation -> `master`

My Client/s -> `branch` or `branch1`, `branch2` etc

We will be distributing the *same* app(with certain tweaks like UI and small feature changes) to various clients

My organisation(master) developed an app which needs to be distributed among the client’s employees and for their internal use. I recently uploaded the app using MY organisation’s Apple developer account(master) but they rejected saying it’s for client’s internal use so I should prefer Apple Business Manager(ABM) .

Since **ABM** requires **MDM** which my client does not want(because the employees use their personal devices) , should I go for Apple Enterprise Program ?

Since we will distribute the same app to multiple clients, I had a few questions for it :

1. Can my organisation(`master`) purchase and enroll in the "Apple Developer Enterprise Program" and distribute the app privately to our client's(`branch`) employees and other clients in the same manner. Here the account will be purchased in our organisation's name(`master`) and the apps that we want to deploy will be of our client's(`branch1`, `branch2` etc) so that each of our clients need not purchase separate account and go through the enrolment process
2. If not, can we(`master`) purchase the account (Apple Developer Enterprise Program) on the behalf of our client using the information(required for enrolment process) they provide so that they don't need to go through the enrolment process i.e. The account will be purchased in the name of our clients(`branch`) but we create their account(as in on their behalf) using the information they provide used for enrolment process so that they need not go through the enrolment process themselves and we create it for them
3. If my client already has an Apple Developer account(non enterprise), can they upgrade that to  Apple Developer Enterprise or do they have to buy a separate new one. Also, can they use that account(enterprise one) to upload apps to the *public* App Store

Comment: The terms of the enterprise program require that you only use it to distribute apps to devices that your organisation owns. You really need an MDM to manage apps distributed under the enterprise program anyway as the provisioning profile and distribution certificates need to be updated periodically. To get an enterprise program papers need to be signed by an authorised signatory from the organisation, so you cannot do it on your clients behalf. You cannot "upgrade" an non-enterprise program to an enterprise program. You can hold both a standard and enterprise program at the same time

Comment: MDM and ABM is the way that you should recommend. With iOS 13 personal devices can be enrolled in an MDM with a partition between personal data and corporate data. The company can only erase apps and data that they have added to the device. Personal data is retained.

Comment: @Paulw11 `distribute apps to devices that your organisation owns` - That means I cannot distribute the app to the employee's personal device using Enterprise ? Also, is it really necessary to integrate MDM with enterprise as the client really don't want to go in for MDM (They always compare the ease of deploying apps in Android to our case)

Comment: The terms of the enterprise agreement state that it is only for the organisation's employees. I believe that private devices are ok. Without an MDM you will need to provide a new version every 12 months and the users will need to manually install the new version or the app will stop working.